# Django Tastypie, Remove Elements From ManyToMany Fields

Tags: tastypie

I am using Tastypie, Django for my project.
To Update a many to many field I have used save_m2m hook.

```
def save_m2m(self, bundle):
      for field_name, field_object in self.fields.items():
        if not getattr(field_object, 'is_m2m', False):
            continue

        if not field_object.attribute:
            continue

        if field_object.readonly:
            continue

        related_mngr = getattr(bundle.obj, field_object.attribute)
        related_objs = []
        print bundle.data[field_name]
        for related_bundle in bundle.data[field_name]:
          try:
            stock = Stock.objects.get(nse_symbol = related_bundle.obj.nse_symbol)
            print stock.__dict__
          except Stock.DoesNotExist as e:
            dataa = {"error_message": e}
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=HttpBadRequest(content=json.dumps(dataa), content_type="application/json; charset=UTF-8"))
          related_objs.append(stock)
        related_mngr.add(*related_objs)
```

Now I want to remove elements from the same many to many field.

How should I achieve this. Do I have to send a patch request or delete request and how to handle this.

I am begineer in tastypie. I googled it some time and I couldn't find a proper way. Please guide me how to complete this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought a lot about handing m2m relationships, since most of our app depends on m2m links.

I've settled for the approach of an `update` method. Pass in the all the references of the relationships you want changed (add and remove), then update the db accordingly. We only pass in the changed values, since if you have a paginated list, you only want to update the items the user has identified. Generally I use a custom hook for this defined in `override_urls`.

I used to have a separate add and remove method, which worked well until we changed the gui and allowed users simply to change checkboxes. In that approach having an `update` method was much more useful. You'll have to decide on which method suits your application the best.